# mysql aggregate function promblem( how to add up values before and after a specific value within the same group)

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on some data which I got from work and I am trying to come up a query that make my life a far more easier (I took the time to import those data on mysql.)

I have bunch of samples that have different values (Area) at different times (kinda like bell curves), so all I need to do is to add up every peaks (area) before the biggest peak and every peaks (Area) after the biggest peak (so two column in total) at each samples. The task sounds really simple, but I am having a very tough time to come up with aquery that works.

I came up with something like that, but the problem is that I can't do "group by" in the where clause because of returns of multiple rows in the subquery, so I can't compare the values in within the samples. I tried couple different approaches, but none of them are going anywhere.  Any helps would be appreciated.

```
SELECT Sample_name, sum(per_area) As '% area'/*For the areas before the peak.*/
FROM W_data.SEC_results
Where retention between /*retention =  time */
0 
AND 
(( select retention
from  W_data.SEC_results
where per_area = ( 
select max(per_area)
from W_data.SEC_results /* select the largest area in the entire set, instead of a specific samples */
)))
group by vial;
```

Table:

```
+----------------------------------+------+-------------+----------+
| Sample_name                      | vial | retention   | per_area |
+----------------------------------+------+-------------+----------+
| a                                | 74   | 14.146      |   0.08   |
| a                                | 74   | 16.624      |  99.79   |
| a                                | 74   | 20.343      |   0.13   |
| b                                | 75   | 12.438      |   0.16   |
| b                                | 75   | 13.653      |   1.85   |
| b                                | 75   | 16.588      |  97.95   |
| b                                | 75   | 20.316      |   0.04   |

+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| sample_name | Area( before)  |Area (after) |  
+-------------+----------------+-------------+
| a           | 0.08           |   0.13      |
| b           | 2.01           |   0.04      |
```

Comment: your problem is difficult to understand? can you also provide the table structure?

Comment: The actual table is far more complicated but I will typed up the simplified one

Comment: what should be your result table with this sample data?

Comment: One random question. How can I paste the table with proper format on this forum .

Comment: Indent every line with 4 spaces to make it look like a citation (edit your post and look at what I've done to your first table)

Answer (score 1):

logic is:-
first find maximum per_area for all vial

```
select vial,max(per_area) maxarea from sec_results group by vial
```

| 74   |  99.79   |

| 75   |  97.95   |

then find respective time for them

```
select sr.vial,sr.time,mt.maxarea from sec_results sr,
    (select vial,max(per_area) maxarea from sec_results group by vial) mt
```

| 74   | 16.624      |  99.79   |

| 75   | 16.588      |  97.95   |

and sum up the values below and above those time seperately.

```
select a.sample_name,sum(if(a.time<temp.time,a.per_area,0)) Area_before,
       sum(if(a.time>temp.time,a.per_area,0)) Area_after 
from sec_results a, (select sr.vial,sr.time,mt.maxarea 
                     from sec_results sr,(select vial,max(per_area) maxarea 
                                          from sec_results 
                                          group by vial) mt
                     where sr.vial = mt.vial
                     and sr.per_area = mt.maxarea
                    ) temp
where a.vial = temp.vial
group by a.vial,a.sample_name;
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question so quickly. it is going to take  some time for me to understand the code.

Comment: I tried your query on my table, but the numbers does not come out right.

Comment: I think the 2nd a.time in the if statement should be the sum of a.per_area. i.e if (a.time<temp.time, sum(a.per_area),0)(of course, it comes up with the wrong result because it includes every values) and also every area_after  comes out as 0

Comment: ok, I came up with the solution. Since I am a newbie on the website, so I can't answer my own question, but I basically modify your query by putting it as subquery on the from clause and select sum of area_before and area_after, grouped by sample_name

Comment: You appear to be missing the SUM function around the IF statements for area_before and area_after

Comment: I found out problems after I have been using this query for awhile. Some sample has a duplicated values for Area_before and Area_after. so the sum values is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just been doing this for interest. Was trying to come up with a way to avoid having an IF inside the SUM to get the correct results.

Have managed it, but don't really think it is efficient. But having gone to the effort I thought I would put them here just for interest.

First way, joining against a pair of sub selects each of which get the sums either before or after:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.sample_name, b.AreaBefore, c.AreaAfter
FROM sec_results a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT sr.vial, SUM(sr_max.per_area) AS AreaBefore
    FROM sec_results sr
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT vial, max(per_area) AS maxarea 
        FROM sec_results 
        GROUP BY vial) Sub1
    ON sr.vial = Sub1.vial
    AND sr.per_area = Sub1.maxarea
    INNER JOIN sec_results sr_max
    ON sr.vial = sr_max.vial
    AND sr.retention > sr_max.retention
    GROUP BY vial
) b
ON a.vial = b.vial
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT sr.vial, SUM(sr_max.per_area) AS AreaAfter
    FROM sec_results sr
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT vial, max(per_area) AS maxarea 
        FROM sec_results 
        GROUP BY vial) Sub1
    ON sr.vial = Sub1.vial
    AND sr.per_area = Sub1.maxarea
    INNER JOIN sec_results sr_max
    ON sr.vial = sr_max.vial
    AND sr.retention < sr_max.retention
    GROUP BY vial
) c
ON a.vial = c.vial
```

2nd way, which is using the subselects to get the sums of the before (or after) records of every record, then joining that against a sub select to get the max one.

```
SELECT a_sec_result.vial, a_sec_result.sample_name, area_before.area AS AreaBefore, area_after.area AS AreaAfter
FROM (
    SELECT sr.vial, sr.sample_name, sr.retention
    FROM sec_results sr
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT vial, sample_name, max(per_area) AS maxarea 
        FROM sec_results 
        GROUP BY vial, sample_name
    ) max_area_sub
    ON sr.vial = max_area_sub.vial
    AND sr.sample_name = max_area_sub.sample_name
    AND sr.per_area = max_area_sub.maxarea 
) a_sec_result
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT sr.vial, sr.retention, SUM(sr2.per_area) AS area
    FROM sec_results sr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sec_results sr2
    ON sr.vial = sr2.vial
    AND sr.retention > sr2.retention
    GROUP BY sr.vial, sr.retention
) area_before
ON a_sec_result.vial = area_before.vial
AND a_sec_result.retention = area_before.retention
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT sr.vial, sr.retention, SUM(sr2.per_area) AS area
    FROM sec_results sr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sec_results sr2
    ON sr.vial = sr2.vial
    AND sr.retention < sr2.retention
    GROUP BY sr.vial, sr.retention
) area_after
ON a_sec_result.vial = area_after.vial
AND a_sec_result.retention = area_after.retention
```

Both should give the right result.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think the first approach also have the same duplication problems

Comment: What kind of duplication problem? Only possible way I can see a duplicate causing an issue is if your max value for a vial is not unique. In such a case what would you like to do?

Comment: hmm, i don't know what cause the duplication ( I hasn't really looked into it) , but the numbers does not add up into the right values ( it 's way too high).